# How to use Method function getParamterTypes()?

Tags: java

I am trying to print out the parameter types for the methods of a generic class, but I am getting garbage values. I am sure I am just making a simple error somewhere, but I am really new to programming so I can't figure out where.

```
static void displayMethodInfo(Object obj){
        Class c = obj.getClass();       
        Method methods[] = c.getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method m : methods){
            if(!Modifier.isPrivate(m.getModifiers()))
                System.out.print(m.getName() + "(");
                System.out.print(m.getParameterTypes() + " -> ");
                System.out.println(m.getReturnType());
        }
    }
```

When I run the program, the parameters types are not printing out, only their memory locations. It should be printing out int and char. Do I need to override something to get them to print out right, or am I just using the function wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does not implement a human-readable version of `toString()` for an array which is being returned by `m.getParameterTypes()`. You could wrap it into a list to print:

```
System.out.print(Arrays.asList(m.getParameterTypes()) + " -> ");
```

The result which is returned by this call would be verbose, so you could convert it into `String[]` using `Class.getSimpleName` for each of the return parameter types:

```
public static String[] toSimpleNames(Class... classes){
    String[] names = new String[classes.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        names[i] = classes[i].getSimpleName();
    }

    return names;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*getParameterTypes()* returns an array. You need to iterate through it in order to display parameters. See the example in [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodType.html). This is the relevant part:

```
Class<?>[] pType  = m.getParameterTypes();
Type[] gpType = m.getGenericParameterTypes();
for (int i = 0; i < pType.length; i++) {
    out.format(fmt,"ParameterType", pType[i]);
    out.format(fmt,"GenericParameterType", gpType[i]);
}
```